# ASP.NET MVC ViewModel Generics

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, razor

I'm trying to create a view which takes in an instance of my own class `RichListViewModel`, then creates a pretty list of the elements in the view model by invoking `Html.DisplayFor` on each one (trying to keep the app DRY by putting this all in one partial view). However, I'm running into trouble with what type to declare in the .cshtml file... I tried:

```
@model MyProject.ViewModels.RichListViewModel<dynamic>

<ol class="rich @(Model.SetName.ToLower())-list">
    @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    { 
        <li id="@Model.ElementName-controls" class="@Model.ElementName buttons">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Create", Model.SetName, null)" class="button create-button"><span class="icon"></span> <span class="text">Add @Model.SetMemberName</span></a>
        </li>
    }

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    { 
        <li class="@Model.ElementName">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item)
        </li>
    }
</ol>

@if (!Model.Any())
{
    <div class="notice">Sorry, there aren&rsquo;t any @String.Format("{0}s", Model.SetMemberName.ToLower()) available right now. Check back soon, or call us at @Model.PhoneNumber.</div>
}
```

But then I get this message...

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MyProject.ViewModels.RichListViewModel`1[MyProject.ViewModels.SaleViewModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MyProject.ViewModels.RichListViewModel`1[System.Object]'.

The actual `RichListViewModel<T>` is exactly what you'd expect, and compiles fine - it's just a class with a type parameter which implements `IEnumerable<T>` and has the properties necessary to fill in the information above.

Is what I'm attempting possible in a clean way? If so, how do I go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot convert a `RichListViewModel<SaleViewModel>` to a `RichListViewModel<object>`.

If you're passing a `RichListViewModel<SaleViewModel>` to the view, you should declare it as taking a `RichListViewModel<SaleViewModel>`.

Alternatively, you can use a generic covariant interface, which would be convertible.

Comment: I should have clarified - I'm trying to get it so that it will take a `RichListViewModel<SaleViewModel>` or a `RichListViewModel<EventViewModel>`, etcetera. I'm going to try the covariant interface - I was reading about that and it may be my best bet at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You mistake here is assuming generics follow polymorphic rules for the specified type. Google Covariance vs Contravariance

If student derives from person then:

```
List<Student> != List<Person>
```

Here, dynamic (which is essentially object) is not the type you are passing in.
Try use RichListViewModel (taking a stab here)